# Check if there is no consecutive numbers in range

Tags: excel

I've got a range of values. 
I need to check for each value above zero:
If any two values in range are consecutive (located next to each other, like 7 an 8) - type "Yes". 
Otherwise - "No".

Update:
I should have only one answer yes/no for a given range. I need to check if there is at least one instance of consecutive numbers within the range.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that stackoverflow is not a coding service. You should give a code example or at least an idea on how to do it. Please also see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it globally for a list of unsorted numbers (say in A2:A6) then you will need something like this:-

```
=IF(SUM(--(ABS(A2:A6-TRANSPOSE(A2:A6))=1)),"yes","no")
```

This is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

On reflection, each pair is compared forwards and backwards, so the ABS isn't necessary and this should be enough:-

```
=IF(SUM(--(A2:A6-TRANSPOSE(A2:A6)=1)),"yes","no")
```

However as OP stated *for every value above zero*, if it is possible to have negative or zero values and you wanted to exclude them I can't see a shorter way of doing it than checking that both members of every pair are positive like this:-

```
=IF(SUM((A2:A6-TRANSPOSE(A2:A6)=1)*(A2:A6*TRANSPOSE(A2:A6)>0)),"yes","no")
```